# Left/right inverse matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $a,b,c$ does a left and/or right inverse exist for $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
2 & b \\
3 & c
\end{bmatrix}$ exist?

We know that a left inverse matrix $X$ exists such that $XA=I_2$ where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix so $X$ is a $2\times 3$ matrix. What do we do next? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that a left inverse exists? What is that left inverse if $\ a=1\ $, $\ b=2\ $ and $\ c=3\ $?

Comment: Hint: if the equation $xA=b$ has a solution, what is the relationship between $A$ and $b$?

Comment: The fact that "a matrix has left Inverse iff its linear map is an injection and has right inverse iff its linear map is a surjection" may help.

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can view $A$ as a map from $\mathcal{R}^2$ to $\mathcal{R}^3$.

Having a left inverse is impossible if $A$ is not an one to one mapping.

Image of the mapping $A$ is the column space of $A$.

If the columns space is 1-dimentional then $A$ is not one to one (because by rank-nullity theorem, kernel of $A$ is no trivial).

So to have a left inverse we need $[a,b,c]$ not a multiple of $[1,2,3]$ to guaranty that image of $A$ is not 1-dimentional.

Having a right inverse is impossible as there are no mapping $X$ that is one to one from $\mathcal{R}^3$ to $\mathcal{R}^2$.

Comment: So would that be the opposite if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
a & b & c
\end{bmatrix}$ meaning a left inverse is impossible in this case?

Comment: In this case, $A$ could have right inverse but can't have left inverse and rank of row space is the same as rank of column space. so making $[a b c]$ not a multiple of $[1 2 3]$ would work.